# How to write encryption string in pdf with itext

Tags: java, pdf, encryption, fonts, itext

I am trying to write an `IV` (Initialization Vector), a `key` and a secret `token` in a pdf (IV and key are from javax.crypto). The mean of doing this is to write protected data in a password-protected text file (So you can easily read data from the code, but not from a reader).

The following is how I initialize every string (byte arrays that I convert to string)

IV :

```
byte[] iv = new byte[128/8];
SecureRandom srandom = new SecureRandom();
srandom.nextBytes(iv);
String iv = new String(ivb, "UTF-8");
```

Key :

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
byte[] keyb = skey.getEncoded();
String key = new String(keyb, "UTF-8");
```

Secret token :

```
byte[] stringBytes = TOKEN.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] encodedBytes = cipher.doFinal(stringBytes);
String token = new String(tokenb, "UTF-8");
```

After that, I write every string in a pdf :

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("arialuni.ttf", 
BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, zrsz);
writer.setEncryption("ownerPass".getBytes(), "userPass".getBytes(), 0, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
writer.createXmpMetadata();
document.open();

document.add(new Paragraph(iv, new Font(bf, 22)));
document.newPage();
document.add(new Paragraph(key, new Font(bf, 22)));
document.newPage();
document.add(new Paragraph(token, new Font(bf, 22)));
```

but the result are different for pdf files. For example, for the IV string

First image : IV in notepad using FileOutputStream for a .txt
;  Second image : IV in Acrobat Reader using document.add(new Paragraph)

[image: IV in notepad using FileOutputStream for a .txt]

[image: IV in Acrobat Reader using document.add(new Paragraph)]

Some characters gets lost when using iText `document.add(new Paragraph)`. I read on other question that I should use a font that can recognize the characters I'm trying to write. So I am asking if the font is the problem, or it could be something else.

Comment: String is not a container for arbitrary bytes: `String key = new String(keyb, "UTF-8");` is incorrect.

Comment: Consider using base64 encoded data.

Comment: "You should absolutely not use an Encoding to convert arbitrary binary data to text. Encoding is for when you’ve got binary data which genuinely is encoded text - this isn’t.

Instead, use Convert.ToBase64String to encode the binary data as text, then decode usingConvert.FromBase64String." Jon Skeet